# Java - <anonymous State$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method next() in State

Tags: java

I got this error message after complied the code

> < anonymous State$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract
>   method next in State.

States.java

```
enum States implements State {
Init { //error message here
        @Override
        public State next(Input word) {
            switch(word.read()) {
                case 'a': return A;
                default: return FinalStates.Failed;
            }
        }
    },
...
```

State.java

```
interface State {
    public State next();
}
```

Comment: The parameter is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface's declaration and the enum's definition have different signatures. The interface doesn't have the word parameter.

Comment: Either add the parameter in the interface or remove it in the enum constant.